# Keep SQL bit as 0/1 rather than boolean in vb.net command results

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

I have an ASP VB.NET app that acts as a go-between for an HTML client and a SQL Server database. SQL MSE shows the result set of bit columns as 0/1 as I would anticipate, but it seems that VB.NET converts them to boolean.

```
 Private command As New SqlCommand
 Private returnDataTable As New DataTable
 Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
 command = New SqlCommand("", Me.conn) With {
            .CommandText = "",
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        }
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("", )
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(returnDataTable)
```

In this example, `returnDataTable`'s rows contain booleans rather than byte or int or some numeric type when I JSON serialize it. I can simply send the boolean "False"/"True" to the client but would rather send 0/1 if possible, and without having to parse through the datatable to do so.

Is there a way to change this functionality?

Comment: select convert(tinyint, MyBitColumn) will return a number not a bool.

Comment: That's likely as good a place as any to handle it, thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

As I have control over the queries, I could convert the bit columns to tinyint in the query and they are handled properly.